# Rendering HTML from external javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a task to show my product list on my client's websites. My idea is include my JavaScript file in client's websites call a function like this,

```html
    <div id="my-product-list"></div>

    <script src="https://example.com/myscript.js"></script>
        const myproducts = new Products('#my-product-list', 12323);
        myproducts .setup();
    </script>
```

Is this the right way to achieve this?

If yes, How can I include css styles(`media` queries) for my elements?

If no, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing what you're suggesting is a viable solution, however the way you have it wouldn't work as you're ending a script tag, and not starting it for your function call.

It should be like this:

```html
    <div id="my-product-list"></div>

    <script src="https://example.com/myscript.js"></script>
    <script>
        const myproducts = new Products('#my-product-list', 12323);
        myproducts.setup();
    </script>
```

Comment: Oh I have missed the starting script tag. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes! That is certainly a way to achieve what you need.

To include styles you can simply make a link to your styles in the same way you reference your script.

**Clients Website**

```
<div id="my-product-list"></div>

<script src="https://example.com/myscript.js"></script>
<script>
  initProducts('#my-product-list', '31337')
</script>

<link href="https://example.com/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**myscript.js**

```
function initProducts(selector, clientId) {
  const baseEl = document.querySelector(selector)
  if (baseEl) {
    fetch('http://example.com/products/' + clientId)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        baseEl.innerHTML = data
      });
  } else {
    console.warn('baseEl not found', selector)
  }
}
```

**mystyles.css**

```
#my-product-list {
  ...
}

#my-product-list div {
  ...
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  #my-product-list {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: products lists can be different according to the client's id. in my example client is is 12323. how to pass client id from your solution?

Comment: I've edited my answer to allow passing of the clientId. My example assumes that the clientId is used to perform a GET request to get the product data but you can modify it as required